# SKlearn fit error float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to training a model when there is a set of features like:

```
Feature 1: [1.0, 2.5, 5.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.5, 1.0, 2.5,...
Feature 2: [112240.0, 200005.1, 100000.5, 60000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6500000000, 10000000]
```

In the preprocessing, when I try the fit for rescale with the following code:

```
X, y= dataset[['JCD','Tamura','ColorLayout','EdgeHistogram','AutoColorCorrelogram','PHOG']],dataset.category



#encode labels
targetNames = np.unique(y)
le= LabelEncoder()
target= le.fit_transform(y)
y=np.array(target)

#Normalization
scaler            = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
rescaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(X)
X=rescaled_features
print (X.JCD.describe())
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Comment: On which line are you getting this TypeError?